# Memory allocation in C application

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I'm currently writing a small application to re-familiarise myself with C (it's been a while since I last wrote any) and like most people do, I've run into a memory allocation issue which I cannot figure out.

The code revolves around the setting up of different panels, windows and the associated titles. Precisely it's the allocation of memory for the title string I'm having trouble with.

The base is a structure which contains:

```
struct TFB_PANEL
{
    WINDOW *window;
    char *title;
};
```

This is typedef'd in the header file as:

```
typedef struct TFB_PANEL TfbPanel;
```

In the related C file I have the following method which initialises an array `TFB` of a fixed size.

```
int tfb_init()
{
    if (!_initialised) {
        return -1;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TYPE_MAX; i++) {
        TFB[i] = malloc(sizeof(TfbPanel*));
        TFB[i]->title = calloc((strlen(TYPES[i]) + 18), sizeof(char*));
        switch(i)
        {
            case A:
                sprintf(TFB[i]->title, " %s | r | h | s | t ", TYPES[i]);
                break;
            case B:
                sprintf(TFB[i]->title, " f | %s | h | s | t ", TYPES[i]);
                break;
            case C:
                sprintf(TFB[i]->title, " f | r | %s | s | t ", TYPES[i]);
                break;
            case D:
                sprintf(TFB[i]->title, " f | r | h | %s | t ", TYPES[i]);
                break;
            case E:
                sprintf(TFB[i]->title, " f | r | h | s | %s ", TYPES[i]);
                break;
        }

        TFB[i]->window = tfb_create_window(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the error occurs when C is initialised. A and B get set correctly to a length of 25 characters. C on the other hand should contain 24 characters after initialisation but instead (from within tfb_create_window) I recieve

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory
Reason: 13 at address 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff930b9390 in strcmp()
```

Examining the stack shows TFB[C] being initialised correctly but the title element is not. This contains a null element as if I had never made the call to calloc.

Please can someone explain where I am going wrong with this or why A and B get initialised correctly but C kills the app. Everything was going beautifully until about 6am this morning, it's been down hill since then.

If it helps, `tfb_create_window` is defined with a call to `_create_window` and a call to `tfb_get_title` as follows:

```
char *tfb_get_title(int type)
{
    if (type >= TFB_MAX) {
        return (char*)NULL;
    }
    return TFB[type]->title;
}

WINDOW *tfb_create_window(int type)
{
    int height = ((LINES - WIN_OFFSET_Y) / 3);
    char *title = tfb_get_title(type);
    return _create_window(height, WIN_SIDEBAR_X, WIN_OFFSET_Y, 0, COLOUR_MAIN, title);
}

WINDOW *_create_window(int height, int width, int starty, int startx, int color, const char *title)
{
    WINDOW *window;
    window = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
    box(window, 0, 0);
    mvwprintw(window, 0, 2, title);
    wbkgd(window, COLOR_PAIR(color));
    return window;
}
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but note that you're actually allocating too _much_ memory at one point: `calloc((strlen(TYPES[i]) + 18), sizeof(char*))`. This allocates space for `(strlen(TYPES[i]) + 18` char _pointers_, which is probably 4 or 8 times as much memory as you really need.

Comment: I thought as much, I was originally allocating only `strlen(TYPES[i]) + 18` but I added the multiplier whilst trying to fix it. I've also tried just using `malloc(strlen(TYPES[i]) + 18)` but to no avail.

Comment: @mplf Are you sure you want to do this `malloc(sizeof(TfbPanel*))` instead of `malloc(sizeof(TfbPanel))` ? Also, what is `TFB[i]`?

Comment: Memory for TfbPanel isn't the issue, regardless of which way round I allocate memory for the panel I still get the exact same bad access signal from the string comparison. `TFB[i]` is a pointer to a valid block of memory which previously was working fine until I added the dynamic title in. The `TFB` array is defined as: `TfbPanel *TFB[TYPE_MAX]`

Comment: I mean you want the size of pointer to be your size of `TfbPanel` object?

Comment: I think that is a separate issue which is clouding the real problem I'm trying to solve. I've changed it to using the size of `struct TfbPanel` and I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: And what about the `sizeof(char*)` to `sizeof(char)` ?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here as well :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of bugs in this code, the most severe is, that you use `sizeof(Type*)` instead of `sizeof(Type)`. The later is the actual size of the object, the first is just the size of a pointer to that object (which is 8 bytes on 64 bit machines).

That means, that `malloc(sizeof(TfbPanel*))` allocated too little memory for your `TfbPanel`, so the rest of the program has undefined behaviour.

The `calloc()` is wrong in the same way, but uncritical, because you allocate eight times as much memory as you need.

However, the `calloc()` call has another bug: you add 18 to the result of `strlen()`, which is the number of payload characters you add in your `sprintf()` calls. Which is one too few, because the result of `strlen()` does not include the null byte.

If you can use a POSIX-2008 compliant libc (like the glibc on linux systems), you can use `asprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`, it will automatically malloc enough space for the resulting string, avoiding any possible buffer size errors. If you can't use that function, use at least `snprintf()` to avoid accessing unallocated memory.

Comment: Based on the comments so far I'd already swapped out the assignment of `malloc(sizeof(TfbPanel*))` to use `malloc(sizeof(struct TfbPanel))` - the key issue as you rightly pointed out was 1 too few characters to the string. I've added this in and it's resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you step through with gdb to this line:

```
sprintf(TFB[i]->title, " f | r | %s | s | t ", TYPES[i]);
```

What is the values of TYPES[i]?

Comment: TYPES is a fixed array defined as char *TYPE[] = {"feature", "release", "hotfix", "support", "trunk"};

Comment: what is the value of `TYPE_MAX`?

Comment: `enum` ranging from A - TYPE_MAX corresponding to the key values from the TYPE array